# I'm currently walking (mostly) around Taiwan. When telling locals this, which of the many words for "walk" is the best to use?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, taiwan

I'm currently walking around Taiwan. Well mostly I'm walking, but I'm also interspersing some hitchhiking.

**EDIT:** By "walking around" I don't mean "here and there", I mean literally "around" the whole island, mostly following 環島1號線, but sometimes on other highways or smaller roads.

[image: route sign]

When telling locals in Chinese what I'm doing, which word for "walk" is the best to use?

Here are some of the words for "to walk" in Mandarin that I've come across so far:

- 步行 (bùxíng)
- 健行 (jiànxíng)
- 散步 (sànbù)
- 徒步旅行 (túbù lǚxíng)
- 遠足 / 远足‎(yuǎnzú)
- 走 (zǒu)
- 行走 (xíngzǒu)
- 走路 (zǒulù)

If the preferred word varies by region, I'd want the one most appropriate in Taiwan. But just in Mandarin since I haven't learned any Taiwanese.

Comment: 健行(徒步旅行,远足)bkrs: hike 以徒步方式，到郊外旅游的活动。此种活动起源于西元一九○一年德国费施尔中学，后流行于世界各地。行走(走路)[walk; go on foot] 行路; 走动
jukuu:四处溜达，看看风景 walk around and see the sights.绕着街区缓缓散步walk around the block,在城里到处闲逛walk around the city

Comment: @user6065: I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: I know you added an update but I think you could clarify further your question by asking how to say "walk [the whole way] around the island". "Walking around" still doesn't mean what you want it to mean...

Answer (score 1):

"徒步環島" or "環島步行" is most appropriate for "walking around taiwan".

"環島" is around the island.

great activity, how many days you need? and where're you now?

have fun :)

Comment: I'm stopping all the time for varying lengths of time. There's no exact plan. I arrived in Taiwan on August 4 and started walking from 淡水 / 八里 on August 16. I've been resting in 恆春 for about six days, since just before the super typhoon.

Comment: half way now :) i wish that i can do it before i die, but it has a lower priority in my "wish-to-do-in-my-life" list. btw, if you are alone, you've one more choice: "環島獨行", that 獨 means alone. when you mention this one, most likely you would trigger sympathy :)

Answer (score 1):

If by saying "walking around Taiwan",  you meant " touring Taiwan on foot." then「徒步遊覽台灣 」is the appropriate phrase.
If you meant " wandering around Taiwan on foot" then saying「徙步漫遊台灣」is proper.

update:

Traveling along the entire coast line of Taiwan on foot is 「環台(島)步行」; Traveling across Taiwan on foot is 「橫台(島)步行」

Comment: Sorry I forget there's two senses of "around" in English. There's a road or series of roads that go around the island in a ring. Many people travel around the ring by motorbike, scooter, or bicycle. I'm not strictly following this "bicycle route 1" but I'm mostly on that route.

Comment: I live in Canada, 橫加步行 is possible, but 環加步行 may be impossible because Canada is not an island, and the northern part is close to the North pole

Comment: Even in English it's tricky to pick the right words since "hiking" or "trekking" give a sense that I'd be offroad in the countryside but I'm walking along the roadways.